# Python Dictionary using keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

group_by owners

My code:

```
def group_by_owners(files):
  for key in files.keys():
    if files[key] in files:
      return files[key],key

files = {
  'Input.txt': 'Randy',
  'Code.py': 'Stan',
  'Output.txt': 'Randy'
}   
print(group_by_owners(files))
```

Expected output:

```
{'Randy': ['Input.txt','Output.txt'], 'Stan':['Code.py']}
```

Comment: Hi, could you try adding more textual description? Your question is quite straight forward, but a more complex example would cause some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_by_owners(files):
    new_dic = dict() # Our new dict.
    for key, val in files.items():
        if val in new_dic: # If we have this name
            new_dic[val].append(key) # Then just add the file
        else:
            new_dic[val] = [key] # Else create a new list with this file for this name
    return new_dic
```

**Output:**

```
{'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```